# ng-maxlength not working for a variable

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm trying to use `ng-maxLength` directive to give a variable max-length for my inputs.

```
function ValidatorCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = "Star";
  $scope.$metadata={};
  $scope.$metadata.isRequired = true;
  $scope.$metadata.maxLength=5;
}


     <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-maxlength="$metadata.maxLength"   
ng-required="$metadata.isRequired" name="name" />
```

But it doesn't seems to be working as expected. When it is applied the model binding for the same variable is not working. [Here is my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHNaswIIZqcdrOurYXVM?p=preview)

If I remove ng-maxLength `ng-required` is going to work as expected , otherwise `ng-required` is also not working.

Comment: I think it's a bug https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1405 if you put directly 5 it works it seems ng-maxlength="{{$metadata.maxLength}}" to work

Comment: `ng-maxlength="{{$metadata.maxLength}}"` seems to be working

Comment: Yeah seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

ng-maxlength does not take scope values.
Traditionally ng-maxlength is used as such ng-maxlength="3".
You can either add curly braces around your scope value or create a directive that binds scope value inside ng-maxlength.